# Php error code when returning from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "images";
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$ti = null;
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `denied` WHERE ip-adress ='".$ip."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "Sorry " . $row['Name'] . " you have been banned from this site";
}
else {
    echo "<form action='' method='POST'> Enter name to continue: <br/> <input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Enter Name'> <input type='submit' name='continue' value='Continue'> </form> ";
}
```

For Some reason it returns the error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\test\test.php on line 218

The line in question is this one:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

but I am positive it has something to do with the line:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `denied` WHERE ip-adress ='".$ip."'";'
```

Comment: Please use four spaces for each line of code instead of a `>` to get the correct syntax highlighting.

Comment: I guess you should not use that concatenation `'".$ip."'`. I think you should use a parametrized query. Take a look here, as it sould not be that hard to figure out. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Dan's wrong about the error, but right about the principle.

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah, I've noticed that the dash is the problem here.

Comment: The dash was indeed the problem thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is the column name in your WHERE clause:

```
WHERE ip-adress
        ^ hyphen (a.k.a. minus)
```

The hyphen in MySQL has special meaning, and it thinks you want to do a subtraction.

I.e.: `ip` **minus** `address` is what it is interpreted as.

You need to wrap that column in ticks

```
WHERE `ip-adress`
```

Full line:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM denied WHERE `ip-adress` ='".$ip."'";
```

Checking for errors against the query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  would have thrown you something about it.

Either that, or rename your column to have an underscore instead of a hyphen.

Since you're using sessions, make sure that the session was started.

`session_start();` isn't in your posted code.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Yeah changing the collum name fixed thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The error message in fact says that the object `$conn` does not exist, you can read that as 'It was not successfully created' if you will.

In any case you could see if the object is looking good by trying: `print_r($conn)`

Maybe you should try to connect like that instead:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `denied` WHERE ip-adress ='".$ip."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
...
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: It's still gives the same error thanks for the help though

Comment: What happens if you try to `print_r($conn)` ?